# Find all maximal ideal of an external direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, finite-fields, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Question:
>   Let $R=\mathbb{Z}_{8}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{30}$.
>   Find all the maximal ideals of R and for each maximal ideal I, identify the size of the field R/I.

I am left stuck with this question.

Here are some helpful theorems:

> Let I be a proper ideal of a commutative ring R.
>   Then, I is a maximal ideal of R if B is an ideal of R and whenever $I\subseteq B\subseteq R$ then either I=B or I=R.
>
> Let I be an ideal of a commutative ring R with unity and I is an ideal of R.
>   Then, R/I is a field if and only if I is a maximal ideal of R.

Any help is appreciated. Please get me going. 
**Hints** preferably.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ideals of $A\oplus B$ are of the form $I\oplus J$ for ideals $I\trianglelefteq A$ and $J\trianglelefteq B$, in which case we have an isomorphism $(A\oplus B)/(I\oplus J)\cong(A/I)\oplus(B/J)$. (Exercise: prove this.)

Comment: Following on from arctic's comment. If you want the quotient to be a field i.e. the ideal to be maximal, then what can you say about $I$ and $J$ in $I\oplus J$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Let $R$ be the ring $A \times B$.

**Lemma:** Every ideal of $R$ is of the form $I \times J$, where $I$ is an ideal of $A$, $J$ is an ideal of $B$.

(Hint: If $\mathfrak a$ is an ideal of $R$, you would obtain $I$ and $J$ by looking at the projection maps $R \rightarrow A, R \rightarrow B$, which are surjective ring homomorphisms)

**Exercise**: if $\mathfrak a$ is an ideal of $R$, give a nice description of $R/\mathfrak a$.

(Hint: using the lemma, it is exactly what you expect.)

Finally, note that if $S,T$ are nonzero rings, then the product $S \times T$ is *never* a field, even if $S$ and $T$ are.